# In what cases iOS stops screen recording on its own?

Tags: ios, screen-capture, screen-recording

I tried making multiple sessions of screen recording on two devices, each recording its own screen: iPhone X and iPhone 5S. The result was that recordings on 5S were in several cases shorter than on X, but I didn't explicitly stop the recording in 5S's Control Center.

**Under which conditions could iOS stop the recording at its own initiative / basing *implicitly* on what I did?**

I found only "tapping status bar" that could stop recording (though it asks for user confirmation); is there anything else?

Comment: Did you do roughly the same stuff on both devices? Did you try to access any private information or anything like that? Those are the only things I can think of software wise. Otherwise it could just be because the 5S is quite old and not capable of recording as smoothly and error free.

Comment: _"Did you do roughly the same stuff on both devices?"_--yes. _"Did you try to access any private information or anything like that?"_--none that I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, locking the phone (pressing the power button once shortly) will also stop recording.

Just like anything else, it requires enough free space on your iPhone to save the file. However, that doesn’t sound like the problem in your case.

There might be a chance that your iPhone 5S might not fast enough or have enough memory to record as long as your iPhone X.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the reasons [already mentioned by David E](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313554/in-what-cases-ios-stops-screen-recording-on-its-own/313594#313594), I also experienced recording stopped when:

1. battery was too low (but long before shutting down)
2. overheating and/or overloaded (eg. running screen recording alongside full-resolution foreground dashcam app and still having active third-party turn-by-turn navigation app in background; sometimes with Personal Hotspot enabled)

Answer (score 1):

When I do screen recording while Playing it’s happens to stop recording. It’s because of my over heating. Before every two games I keep my iPhone refrigerator for 30seconds to 1 minute. Then works without any problem. Its funny but works as expected.

Comment: Overheating was already mentioned in [earlier answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322951/54644).